# If I'm using MAMP, where should I install selenium server on a Mac?

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-rc, yii

I'm using a book to learn Yii, and it's telling me to install selenium server to do functional testing. Where is the best place to install this if I'm using Mac.

(Note, I'm a newbie so explicit instructions are most appreciated.)

Also, would I have to alter the include Path or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For beginning you should use [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/download/)  for firefox. I recommend you play with it before starting advanced use of selenium. Thats all for beginning.

Once comfortable with IDE,You can download this [standalone Selenium Server](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.0a4.jar&can=4&q=)

and then run it with `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b2.jar`

It will run by default on localhost:4444.

You will need client driver for specific language you want to write your tests, if at all. You can get the drivers from [here](http://seleniumhq.org/download/)